# How to extract text from html page?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-applications

How to extract text from html page? For example the web page is the link http://www.atempodihockey.it/campionati/campionati-hil/serie-a1-2013-2014/calendario.html from I want to take the text. I must have the name of the team and the resoult of the match

Comment: Do you want to extract text from whole html page?

Comment: Use 'HtmlAgilityPack' to get the html page

Comment: But i have problem with HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 1):

I think below code can help u

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webterms);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings()
                .setUserAgentString(
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
```

after creating your webview load your url or html page

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(),"HTMLOUT");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url1) {
                    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.documentElement.innerText);");

                }
            });
            webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Then create a class which has a one method for processing your html

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {

        public void processHTML(String html) {
            if (null != html && html.trim().length() > 0) {
                System.out.println("your Html  ->" + html);         
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show me the program in only one page because I have some problem to copy three different part into my program.thanks

Comment: From what I have found you must put `@JavascriptInterface` on the line before the processHtml function declaration

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Do it as follwing...

Add reference of HtmlAgilityPack in your project.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

and then put the url to get the full page

```
HtmlWeb webGet = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = webGet.Load("http://www.atempodihockey.it/campionati/campionati-hil/serie-a1-2013-2014/calendario.html");
```

From the html of 'document' variable you can get your expected text

Comment: When I copy the text that you write I have the problem with var and HtmlWeb (HtmlWeb is a class??)

Comment: Did you add reference to HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: Can you please tell me what the problem is in detail?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET C#? Please try as my edited answer and let me know please

Comment: I don't know...can you write a program for example?

Comment: You decide...for me it's the same thing